# problems importing a class from a another file

Tags: python, import

I am trying to run a program with two files. `file1` contains two classes and one line of code. When I run `file1.py`from the command line the single line of code runs and calls one of the classes from this file. For `file2.py` to work it needs to use just one of the classes from `file1.py`. However no matter what method I use to import this class e.g `from file1 import classA` all that happens when I try to run `file2.py` is that it appears to execute all the code in `file1.py` including the single line, which then runs file1. In short I want access to just a single class from a separate file, not any of the other code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     # put your line of code here
     # add this to file1.py
```

This code will be executed only if your file was *run*, but not if your file was *imported*.

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly now.

Comment: @Paul: you should "accept" Vestel's answer (click checkmark). This indicates to others that you no longer need assistance, and lets Vestel know that you appreciate his help. Cheers.